# OpenCV sparse matrix: how to get the indices of non-zero elements in a row/column

Tags: c++, opencv, sparse-matrix

Is there a way to get the indices of all non-zeros of a specific row of a 2D SparseMat, without looping over the row?

The following code, using a loop, print the results for the y-th row.

```
for(int x = 0; x < sparse_mat.size(1); x++)
{
     if(sparse_mat.ref<int>(y,x) != 0)
            std::cout<<x<<std::endl;  
}
```

Thank you in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have OpenCV, but by reading the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/da9/classcv_1_1SparseMat.html#details) I found this example:

```
// prints elements of a sparse floating-point matrix
// and the sum of elements.
SparseMatConstIterator_<float>
    it = sparse_mat.begin<float>(),
    it_end = sparse_mat.end<float>();
double s = 0;
int dims = sparse_mat.dims();
for(; it != it_end; ++it)
{
    // print element indices and the element value
    const SparseMat::Node* n = it.node();
    printf("(");
    for(int i = 0; i < dims; i++)
        printf("%d%s", n->idx[i], i < dims-1 ? ", " : ")");
    printf(": %g\n", it.value<float>());
    s += *it;
}
printf("Element sum is %g\n", s);
```

along with the following:

> If you run this loop, you will notice that elements are not enumerated
>   in a logical order (lexicographical, and so on). They come in the same
>   order as they are stored in the hash table (semi-randomly). You may
>   collect pointers to the nodes and sort them to get the proper
>   ordering. Note, however, that pointers to the nodes may become invalid
>   when you add more elements to the matrix. This may happen due to
>   possible buffer reallocation.

This implies (kinda explicitly) that the data are stored in a hash table and not as a vector of indices and values, or like [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialSparse.html). It should enable you to sift through the nodes instead of a specific row; something like

```
for(; it != it_end; ++it)
{
    const SparseMat::Node* n = it.node();
    if(n->idx[ROW_INDEX])
        std::cout << n->idx[COL_INDEX] << std::endl;
}
```

Replace `ROW_INDEX` and `COL_INDEX` accordingly, I don't know the relevant order.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. But I think in case the total number of nodes is greater than the number of columns, your solution is even worse: your solution iterates over all the nodes while the solution I proposed in the question iterates over one row.

Comment: Yes, but read the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/da9/classcv_1_1SparseMat.html#a0e1e95540e8cc75976bb4be97dc2203e) carefully. `ref` creates a node if you indicate a non-existent index. You would want to use `ptr` which gives you [control](http://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/da9/classcv_1_1SparseMat.html#a810b96cf23e3cc816e7f99473b81b513) over whether you want to create a missing node or not.

Comment: Good point. But that does not really answer my question :( Maybe such a solution does not exist :(

Comment: As I pointed out, the data are stored in a hash table and not as a sorted vector of indices and values.